# Syncing two folders continuously

Tags: macos, cocoa, synchronization, file-management

I'm trying to get a `for` loop to get all the contents of a directory and copy it to another directory on the system, but I am faced with a dilemma: if I loop through all the files and copy those over to the other directory and vice versa, once a file from either directories is deleted, the loop will just think that the file is *un-synced* and copy it over.

What would be my best bet to sync two separate folders on OS X?

In other words, how can I get one folder accessible from another?

Comment: Make the list of what needs to move before you do any moving.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!, I will not know the items that should be copied over, so how could i make a list for it? :/ im a newbie

Comment: Can you not just symlink one directory to the other? What are you *really* trying to accomplish? Some kind of file-level RAID1 mirroring to get files stored on two different physical volumes, or are you just trying to make the directory accessible from multiple paths?

Comment: Im trying to make them accessible from multiple paths!

Comment: Can no one answer me please?